# to solve Fatal error: Call to a member function id() on a non-object in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have created a custom theme in `drupal 8` and load library according to its requirements. But problems occurred in search page  when search button click getting an error**"Fatal error: Call to a member function id() on a non-object in"**  I have googling not find any related solution. If  anybody knows tell me how to solve this.

**my .theme file**

```
function Endymion_preprocess_page(&$variables) 
{
    if($variables['is_front']) {

    } else {
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
        echo $node->id();

        if($node->id()==35 and $node->getType()=='page') {
            $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'Endymion/MortgageRentvsBuy';
        } else {
            $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'Endymion/MortgageMax'; 
        }

        function Endymion_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
        {      
            $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="container">';
            $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';  
        }
```

Comment: Looks like your Route matcher doesn't return a node here; you could either add a condition for the case node is null (or not a Node object) or start debugging from here.

Comment: thanks....jlapoutre. this error occurs when page search button clicks here search note front page goes to else part and condition check execute error. is search result page is node?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `$node->id()` and everything related to it as shown below.

```
if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
  $example = $node->id();

  ...
}
```